# Building an SQL query in Base SAS for 81 variables to report count of non null values

Tags: sql, sas

I have a data template with 81 exposure elements/ variables and approx 9 million rows for loans generated by a bank for e.g. customer number , reporting date, account number , customer type etc.

I need to conduct data validation to report

1. variable missing or not
2. No of non missing values populated for each available variable
3. the data type of the values populated under each variable

Individually for each variable I'm using the query

```
select COUNT(variable) from library.table where not missing(variable);                                              
quit;
```

How can I extend the above query to all 81 variables ?

I already have the attributes using

```
proc sql;                                                                                                                               
create table test as select * from dictionary.columns where libname="XXX" and memname="tablename";                          
quit;
```

But if the above could be incorporated in one holistic query that could generate an output which I can potentially export as an excel , that would be great

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In SAS there are usually PROCs for this kind of task. For this, it would be the PROC FREQ, e. g. this [example](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2011/09/19/count-the-number-of-missing-values-for-each-variable.html).

If you want an output dataset you can adapt the linked solution and do

```
proc format;
  value $missfmt ' ' = 'Missing' other = 'Not Missing';
  value missfmt . = 'Missing' other = 'Not Missing';
run;

/* Capture the output. */
ods output OneWayFreqs = want;
/* Count missing and not missing. */
proc freq data=have;
  format _char_ $missfmt. _numeric_ missfmt.;
  tables _all_ / missing nocum nopercent;
run;

data want;
  set want;
  array f {*} f_:;
  /* Extract column name. */
  do i = 1 to dim(f);
    if not missing(f[i]) then
      column = substr(vname(f[i]), 3);
  end;
  /* Extract column type. */
  type = vtypex(column);
  /* Get value, i. e. missing or not missing. */
  value = cats(of f_:);
run;

proc sort data=want;
  by column type value;
run;

/* Transpose the missing and not missing rows into two columns. */
proc transpose data=want out=want(drop=_:);
  by column type;
  id value;
  var frequency;
run;
```

Comment: gathering my thoughts to ask you a few questions regarding the code - hoping you will be ok answering them  so I can get on the learning curve